# Adding images as VarBinary(max) in a SQL server DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, postman

Having trouble with adding an Image to a SQL Server DB, wanted to store images as varbinary(max)
Im getting an error in Postman, im I missing something ?
I know i could store the path of the images instead, but i really want to store the image itself.

I have this error in postman : `{ "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13", "title": "Unsupported Media Type", "status": 415, "traceId": "00-5c63bce07398c7b9f783284b002f6d7b-01826e2bbd2b43a1-00" }` 
when adding an image with this code :

```
`Service : 
`   public static async Task<Boolean> AddImage(string conString, Image imageToAdd)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
                {
                    string addImage = "INSERT INTO [Image] ( imageData) VALUES ( @imageData)";
                    using (SqlCommand queryAddImage = new SqlCommand(addImage))
                    {
                        queryAddImage.Connection = con;
                        queryAddImage.Parameters.Add("@imageData", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = imageToAdd.ImageData;
                        con.Open();
                        queryAddImage.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }`

Logic :
`        public static async Task<Response> AddImage(string conString, Image imageToAdd)
        {
            Response response= new Response();
            try
            {
                if(await ImageService.AddImage(conString, imageToAdd))
                {
                    response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.SUCCESS;
                    response.Message = "Image was added to Catalog";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.INTERNALSERVERERROR;
                response.Message = ex.ToString();
            }
            return response;
        }`

Controller: 
`        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddImage(Image imageToAdd)
        {
            string CS = _configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase");
            Response response = await ImageLogic.AddImage(CS, imageToAdd);
            if(response.StatusCode != ComfyCatalogBLL.Utils.StatusCodes.SUCCESS)
            {
                return StatusCode((int)response.StatusCode);
            }
            return new JsonResult(response);
        }`


Model: 
 `public class Image
    {
        public int ImageID { get; set; }
        public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }


        public Image() { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Construtor que visa criar uma Image convertendo os dados obtidos a partir de um SqlDataReader
        /// Construtor presente na layer DAL, que recebe dados para converter num objecto.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rdr">SqlDataReader</param>
        public Image(SqlDataReader rdr)
        {
            this.ImageID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["imageID"]);
            object imageDataObj = rdr["imageData"];
            if (imageDataObj != DBNull.Value)
            {
                this.ImageData = (byte[])imageDataObj;
            }
        }
    }``
```

Comment: Reading the linked [section 6.5.13](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13) shows that the problem isn't with how you're inserting it into the database, but that the problem is with the request itself. Quoting: "the origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload is in a format not supported by this method on the target resource". Maybe it's as easy as adding `[FromForm]` to your `Image imageToAdd` parameter, but I can't tell since I don't what the `Image` class is.

Comment: Instead of Image you would send the image bytes, no? Save it to an MemoryStream and pass that.

Comment: What are you sending via Postman

Comment: i tried uploading jpg and png in postman, as binary and as form-data

Comment: @MindSwipe it worked. Had to change my controller: 
public async Task<IActionResult> AddImage(IFormFile imageFile)

and added this :    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await imageFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
        imageToAdd.ImageData = stream.ToArray();
    }

Thanks alot mate!

Comment: According to [SqlDbType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?view=net-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0): _Varbinary: A variable-length stream of binary data ranging between 1 and 8,000 bytes. Implicit conversion fails if the byte array is greater than 8,000 bytes. Explicitly set the object when working with byte arrays larger than 8,000 bytes_. You should set the size to `-1` in  `Parameters.Add`

Comment: The real trick will be getting the `varbinary(max)` data back out of the database in a state that's sensible to clients. Not sure why you'd go through a .NET `Image` class instead of storing the raw byte stream submitted by the client (Postman or otherwise). i.e.: If you posted a JPEG does the DB value start with 0xffd8ff? For PNG does it start with 0x89504e47?